# What's the point of callback implementation inside function declaration?

Tags: javascript, callback

In the Eloquent Javascript book, in [chapter 6](https://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html) there's the following example:

```
class Matrix {
  constructor(width, height, element = (x, y) => undefined) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.content = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
      }
    }
  }

 //...
}
```

As you can see the 3rd parameter to the constructor is not just a callback parameter, but actually the implementation of the callback.

At first I thought, maybe the body of the implemented callback function is disregarded but at least the future callbacks used in the constructor will be checked to have the same signature. However, I found that the signatures don't matter as the code below will work:

```
const test = new Matrix(2, 4, () => console.log('hello'));
```

So what's the point of implementing callback, it being a parameter of a function? Is just for a reader to infer how many parameters will be passed to the callback?

Comment: As constructed, that callback is the _default value_ of the parameter named `element`. If you pass a callback in, the default implementation is not used. This prevents runtime errors associated with attempting to run a callback that may not have been passed into the class constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify a third parameter, the default value of *element* would be `(x, y) => undefined`.

Please refer to this [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). It will give some insight. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What the example is doing with `element` is to set a default value. In this case the default value does nothing.

Note that you can also use `()=>{}` as default of element, it will work in JavaScript since the language doesn't validate the number of arguments when you call a function (but it may give you a type checking error in TypeScript).

This is a common pattern: instead of using `undefined` or `null`, you put a default parameter that does nothing, so in the code you don't need to check if `element` is defined before calling the function. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern

Some libraries like `lodash` also include constants like `noop` defined as en empty function, so you can write the code as:

```
const noop = ()=>{}

class Matrix {
  constructor(width, height, element = noop) {
//...  
  }
}
```

*Additional information:*

The `Matrix` constructor seems to be initializing a single dimension `Array` to store the matrix. You can replace that nested `for` loop with `Array.from`. Something like:

```
this.contents = Array.from(
  {length: height * width},
  n => element(n % width, Math.floor(n/height))
);
```

I didn't check the math so the example may have index errors. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, it's simply an optional initializer.  If you call it with something like `() = > 0`, it will initialize your matrix with `0` instead of `undefined`.  `(x,y) => x === y ? 1 : 0` would produce an identity matrix. etc ....

(update after reading the chapter)
This is borne out by the sentence following the exemple in the book:

> The constructor function takes a width, a height, and an optional element function that will be used to fill in the initial values.

Answer (score 0):

This class has 3 parameters applying to "Constuctor".

The third one is callback function named "element" is optional, and has default value of "(x,y)=>undefined". So if you did not pass third argument when building a new instance of "Matrix" class it will be as default.

if you pass specific function here (for example)

```
let myMatrix = new Matrix(100,100,(x,y) => x * y);
```

at this stage

```
this.content[y * width + x] = element(x, y);
```

it will returns corresponding values to respective array slots of "this.content" property of your new "Matrix" instance.

So your Matrix will have such "content" property (for example):

```
myMatrix.content[0] = 0;
myMatrix.content[1] = 0;
...
myMatrix.content[101] = 1;
myMatrix.content[102] = 2;
// and so on
```

Otherwise if you don't pass any function when creating a new instance, all generated array slots of "this.content" property will be assigned with undefined values because of default property value of

> (x, y) => undefined